# How to update difference Time using Provider on flutter?

Tags: flutter, difference, provider, flutter-provider

I have class:

```
class JWSModel extends ChangeNotifier {
    String ketCounterShalat = "";
    String diff = "";
    
    void streamDifferentTime() {
        DateTime now = DateTime.now();

        if (now.isBefore(dhuhrTime) && now.isAfter(_dhuha)) {
          ketCounterShalat = "Menuju dhuhur";
          diff = now.difference(dhuhrTime).toString();
        } else if (now.isBefore(asrTime) && now.isAfter(dhuhrTime)) {
          ketCounterShalat = "Menuju ashar";
          diff = now.difference(asrTime).toString();
        } else if (now.isBefore(maghribTime) && now.isAfter(asrTime)) {
          ketCounterShalat = "Menuju maghrib";
          diff = now.difference(maghribTime).toString();
        } else if (now.isBefore(ishaTime) && now.isAfter(maghribTime)) {
          ketCounterShalat = "Menuju isya";
          diff = now.difference(ishaTime).toString();
        } else if (now.isBefore(sunriseTime) && now.isAfter(fajrTime)) {
          diff = now.difference(sunriseTime).toString();
          ketCounterShalat = "Menuju terbit";
        } else if (now.isBefore(_dhuha) && now.isAfter(sunriseTime)) {
          diff = now.difference(_dhuha).toString();
          ketCounterShalat = "Menuju dhuha";
        } else {
          if (fajrTime.day == now.day) {
            diff = now.difference(fajrTime).toString();
          } else if (fajrTime.day != now.day) {
            diff = now.difference(fajrTime.add(const Duration(days: 1))).toString();
          }
        ketCounterShalat = "Menuju subuh";
        notifyListeners();
    }
    
    String get counterShalat => diff;
    String get ketCounter => ketCounterShalat;
}
```

next, in the widget I created

```
class JWS extends StatefulWidget {
  const JWS({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<JWS> createState() => _JWSState();
}

class _JWSState extends State<JWS> {
  
JWSModel jws = JWSModel();

  Future<void> getJWS() async { 
    jws.init();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getJWS();
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      jws.streamDifferentTime();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final state = context.watch<JWSModel>();
    log(state.counterShalat);
```

Why not success? I want to update difference Time, I use a timer to update it. I don't want to use **setState({});** because I think it will be hard to update every 1 second.

Update: if i log in **class JWSModel** success.
But, i call in **class JWS** nothing appears.
i want to get update different time but I don't want to use **setState({});**

or is there the right code for me to use.

Comment: itu `notifilistener()` letakan disetiap if statement, kalau tidak change notifier tidak tau kalau ada perubahan. saya ga tau kalau class `Consumer` itu automatis metrigger `setstate` ketika `notifilistener` terjadi. kenapa ga pakai `streambuilder` aja daripada pakai package buat state management?

Comment: `Consumer` just read the value before the widget rendered,  so its not updated when any changes from `notifyListener()` . 

if you want it, you have to `watch` not just `read` the state

Comment: @SayyidJ Saya mengira fungsi nya sama untuk mengupdate value tanpa merefresh widget kembali, jadi saya menggunakan provider untuk menggantikan setState

Ini masih error: **Tried to use Provider with a subtype of Listenable/Stream**

Comment: @pmatatias this this is still an error: **Tried to use Provider with a subtype of Listenable/Stream**

can you give me example code for update value based on time?

Comment: @RianPratama try my answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
class _JWSState extends State<JWS> {
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      context.read<JWSModel>().streamDifferentTime();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final state = context.watch<JWSModel>();
    return Scaffold ( appBar: AppBar(), 
            body: Text(state.counterShalat, 
                      style:TextStyle(color:Colors.blue)),
    );
}
```

when any update from `notifylistener`, the value should be updated too.

Comment: have you tried this example? @RianPratama

Comment: I just try, and show error this:

**Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (Tried to use Provider with a subtype of Listenable/Stream (JWSModel).**

Comment: you haven't initialized `ChangeNotifierProvider` for `JWSModel` anywhere . you need to initize first

Comment: In main.dart 
I have initialized

`class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<JWSModel>(
          create: (context) => JWSModel(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(`

Comment: not `Provider` but  `ChangeNotifierProvider` 
https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/396#issuecomment-606605394

Comment: providers: [ ChangeNotifierProvider( create: (context) => JWSModel(),
        ),

Comment: Thanks very much, code not error. But, now different time not runing/do not appear.
state.counterShalat

Comment: Is it really like this? class JWSModel extends ChangeNotifier {
or ChangeNotifierProvider ?

if ChangeNotifier , do not appear  state.counterShalat.

Comment: in log() show and success, log(diff);
    log(ketCounterShalat);
    notifyListeners();
} //void streamDifferentTime() {

Comment: `class JWSModel extends ChangeNotifier` this one is correct.

what do you mean do not appear `state.counterShalat`

Comment: **final state = context.watch<JWSModel>();** in widget **Text(state.counterShalat)** Nothing appears

Comment: but in debug console it show correct value??

make sure your text color not same like background color

Comment: if under class JWS not sucees, if under class JWSModel -> streamDifferentTime -> Success

Comment: Or is it suitable for my case what should I use?

Comment: your state is `JWSModel`  , i didnt see any `class JWS` in your question

Comment: i just update code for my question

Comment: @RianPratama try my updated answer, and what you get?

Comment: nothing appears.

Comment: solved, i using Stream.
Thanks very much